# why data is not being set into the List Object in this case?

Tags: java

I am passing two series of data ( colon sperated :) to a method and expecting that to be set inside my Custom class CountryDTO

**This is my CountryDTO class**

```
public class CountryDTO {

    public CountryDTO(String a , String b , String c)
    {

    }
public String value1;
public String value2;
public String value3;

// setters and getters 

}



This is my Main class 

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        Test test = new Test();
        List list = (List) test.extract("IND,US,UK : WI,PAK,AUS");

        Iterator itr = list.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            CountryDTO ind = (CountryDTO) itr.next();
            System.out.println(ind.getValue1());
        }
    }

    public List<CountryDTO> extract(final String v) throws Exception {
        String[] values = v.split(":");
        List<CountryDTO> l = new ArrayList<CountryDTO>();
        for (String s : values) {
            String[] vs = s.split(",");
            l.add(new CountryDTO(vs[0], vs[1], vs[2]));
        }
        return l;
    }
}
```

**What is happening is that , i am getting output as null ( CountryDTO is not being set )**

Could anyone please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, but your DTO is incorrect.  I think it should look like this:

```
public class CountryDTO {

    private final String value1;
    private final String value2;
    private final String value3;

    public CountryDTO(String a , String b , String c) {
        this.value1 = ((a != null) ? a : "");
        this.value2 = ((b != null) ? b : "");
        this.value3 = ((c != null) ? c : "");
    }

    // just getters; no setters 

}
```

I can't speak to what else you code might be doing wrong, but this is certainly off-base.

Answer (score 3):

Because in the `CountryDto` constructor you never set `value1`, nor the other values, so they will remain `null`.

Comment: +1 I suggest you make your fields `final` to ensure they have been set in the constructor correctly.

Comment: I did not get you , could you please let me know whats the difference if its declared final  or not , in this context ?? Thanks in advance ??

Comment: If you used final you would have been warned by the compiler that the field values were not set.